# pandas: replace null values with matchs of the same value in other row but in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I  would like to figure out how to replace null values in pandas/python as follows:

```
| email       | code       | more columns..... |
| --------    | --------   |                   
| hi@gm.com   | 123453     |
| ba@ot.com   | 82734      |
|             | 82734      |
|             | 123453     |
```

I need to fill email column based in code column, as follows:

```
| email       | code       | more columns..... |
| --------    | --------   |                   
| hi@gm.com   | 123453     |
| ba@ot.com   | 82734      |
| ba@ot.com   | 82734      |
| hi@gm.com   | 123453     |
```

Comment: `merge` or `groupby('code')['email'].transform('first')` (assuming real NaNs)